# JavaScript: Need help ordering my JS "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null"

Tags: javascript, html, dom, typeerror

I am an amateur JS person so be kind with your voting as I am new to this.

I am getting Uncaught TypeError:

> Cannot read property 'value' of null.

I realize the issue is with the order of my js and the order in which it is calling DOM, but I am not sure exactly where.

Someone mind helping point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input id="todoItem" type="text" placeholder="Todo Item" />
    <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="insert();" />
  </form>
  <div id="display"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main-2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main-2.js:

```
var todos  = [];

var todoInput  = document.getElementById("todoItem");

var messageBox  = document.getElementById("display");

function insert() {
 todos.push(todoInput.value);

 clearAndShow();
}

function clearAndShow() {

  todoInput.value = "";

  messageBox.innerHTML = "";

  messageBox.innerHTML += "Titles: " + todos.join(", ") + "<br/>";
}
```

Comment: It is unclear from your question - where is your JavaScript code in relation to the HTML code?

Comment: The classic reason for this is that the code is running before the DOM is finished loading, and so `getElementById` cannot find the element.

Comment: @Amadan the code is linked in from my main.js file. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

put this line:

```
var todoInput  = document.getElementById("todoItem");
```

into the function `insert`

when the var todoInput is init the element not exists.

```
function insert() {
  var todoInput  = document.getElementById("todoItem");
  todos.push(todoInput.value);

  clearAndShow();
}
```

to clear input write this code

```
document.getElementById("todoItem").value='';
```

Answer (score 3):

The best investment of time you can make is to **Read and Understand** error messages.

A typical or a common error message in Javascript would be like:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Looking at the first part: `Uncaught TypeError`. `Uncaught` means the error was not caught in a `catch` statement, and `TypeError` is the error’s name.

Looking at the second part, which is more useful than the first part. It is read literally and clearly says, it tried to use `undefined` as a function.

Example:

```
var x = undefined; // 'undefined' is a type in JS
x(); // This is what JS tried to do and said 'Hey! x is undefined. I can't execute it like a function.'
```

In your case, the second part of the error reads: `Cannot read property 'value' of null.`

Visualize this literally. Some context on `property`.

```
var person = {
  'name': 'Joe',
  'age': 10
};
```

Now, `person` is the `object` and `name` and `age` are the `properties` of the `person` object.

Now if you execute `person.name` JS can execute it because person has a property called `name`.

But, if you execute `monster.name`, JS tries to lookup `monster` object. But we don't have `monster` object in our code anywhere. So now JS will `throw`:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: monster is not defined`.

Try to analyze the two parts: `Uncaught ReferenceError`. JS tried to search or refer an object that is not found. Therefore it is `ReferenceError`.

In your case, the DOM is not yet ready when you try to get `todoItem` and hence JS can't find it. So it should be a `ReferenceErrror`. 
 But `document.getElementById()` which is the `DOM` an implementation of ES that searches and modifies the `html` nodes in your markup, will return a `null` object when it cant find something.

`null` is an object in JS. Just like `person` is an object that we declared earlier.

Now your variable `todoInput` will receive the `null` object from `document.getElementById()`
 and tries to search for `value` property in `null` object. And it promptly says in the second part of your error **"Hey! I cant read property `value` from the `null` object"**

Answer (score -2):

You never know your document is loaded if you create variables on fly. Better way is use jquery document.ready if your are using jquery there

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//javascript code goes here
)};
```

OR try your code with these modifications

```
    <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
        <input id="todoItem" type="text" placeholder="Todo Item" />
        <input type="button" value="Save" onclick="insert();" />
      </form>
      <div id="display"></div>
    </body>

    <script>

    var todos  = [];





    function insert() {
var todoInput  = document.getElementById("todoItem");
     todos.push(todoInput.value);

     clearAndShow();
    }

    function clearAndShow() {
    var messageBox  = document.getElementById("display");
      todoInput.value = "";

      messageBox.innerHTML = "";

      messageBox.innerHTML += "Titles: " + todos.join(", ") + "<br/>";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no reason to use jQuery for this. Simply putting the JS at the bottom of the body is entirely enough.