# why do I get ..is not a function?

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create an angular service but getting an error. This is the service:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

// Filter Service that returns records with crdamt positive:
app.factory('FilterService', function() {
  return function(d) {
    var filteredData = [];
    console.log(d);
    d.forEach(function(item) 
    {
      if (item.cramt > 0) {
          filteredData.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filteredData;
  }
});
```

In my unit test however we get:

```
  it('should return transactions where credit is positive', function() {
    var jsonData = {
      "transactions": [{
        "date": "1/1/2000",
        "desc": "Purchase",
        "cramt": 50,
        "dbamt": 0
      }, {
        "date": "1/1/2002",
        "desc": "Transaction",
        "cramt": 110,
        "dbamt": 10
      }]
    };

    var filteredRecords = FilterService(jsonData);
    expect(filteredRecords).toEqual({
      "date": "1/1/2000",
      "desc": "Purchase",
      "cramt": 50,
      "dbamt": 0
    });
  });
```

Why do I get an error:

```
TypeError: d.forEach is not a function
```

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/jdg0wEj1zSDTbqojBAoc?p=preview

Comment: fyi, your test will fail according to that code and test data.

Comment: Either `d` is not an array (in which case it does not support [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) or not using an appropriate modern/shimmed JS version (in which case an array does not support Array.prototype.forEach). In all cases the error message is 100% correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`forEach` method is available on `arrays`. 
Looking at your `jsonData` you can do this:

```
app.factory('FilterService', function() {
  return function(data) {
    var filteredData = [];
    console.log(data.transactions);
    data.transactions.forEach(function(item) 
    {
      if (item.cramt > 0) {
          filteredData.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filteredData;
  }
});
```

**P.S:** Please read the error messages. It clearly says that `d.forEach` is not a functions. It is like trying to define an object like:

```
var person = {
  'name':'Paul'
};
```

and trying to access `person.height()`. The `height` is not a property of `person` object and you are trying to access **`undefined property as a function`**.

[More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30388743/javascript-need-help-ordering-my-js-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property/30389359#30389359)

Answer (score 0):

Just try. I'm expecting variable `d` as an array.

```
angular.forEach(d, function(item){
    if (item.cramt > 0) {
        filteredData.push(item);
    }
});
```

You're not using the right syntax for `forEach` function of angular js. Please refer this [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) directive

Comment: JavaScript supports `arr.forEach` just fine.. if `d` *was* an array (and run in a browser supporting ES5 or a shimmed ES3) it would work as expected. Thus it is likely the case that `d` is *not* an array.. (although it could also be an old browser).

Comment: @user2864740, Thank you so much to share your thoughts.. I will keep it in mind :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your test is trying to filter the entire object instead of the array of transactions.

```
var filteredRecords = FilterService(jsonData);
expect(filteredRecords).toEqual({
  "date": "1/1/2000",
  "desc": "Purchase",
  "cramt": 50,
  "dbamt": 0
});
```

should be

```
var filteredRecords = FilterService(jsonData.transactions);
expect(filteredRecords).toEqual([{
  "date": "1/1/2000",
  "desc": "Purchase",
  "cramt": 50,
  "dbamt": 0
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the updated plnkr. forEach is used for the arrays only and your 'd' returns an object.

Following is the link to the plnkr :

```
``http://plnkr.co/edit/o65e0xEsBiW0jpawhGse?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define filter in this way.

```
app.factory('FilterService', function() {

  return function(d) {
    var filteredData = [];
    var boolDataISFound = false;
     console.log(d.transactions)
    d.transactions.forEach(function(item,index) 
    {
      if (item.cramt > 0) {
          filteredData.push(item);
      }
    });
    return filteredData[0];
  }

});
```

and here is the expectation

```
it('should return transactions where credit is positive', function() {

    var jsonData = [{
      "transactions": [{
        "date": "1/1/2000",
        "desc": "Purchase",
        "cramt": 50,
        "dbamt": 0
      }, {
        "date": "1/1/2002",
        "desc": "Transaction",
        "cramt": 110,
        "dbamt": 10
      }]
    }];

    var filteredRecords = FilterService(jsonData[0]);
     expect(filteredRecords).toEqual({
        "date": "1/1/2000",
        "desc": "Purchase",
        "cramt": 50,
        "dbamt": 0
      } );


  });
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/7fNJdahNRcxQ5cs2PpsD?p=preview)